# High latency, High CPU Interrupts per second 60K/Second causing FPS spikes in games

Tags: cpu, gaming, latency

**CPU Profiling Screenshot:**

[image]

**LatencyMon**

[image]

**Battlefield Screenshot:**

[image]

**Processes:**

[image]

1.3ms of execution time on the NVIDIA Windows Kernal?:

[image]

I'm not familiar with the concept of Interrpts/sec, but after some research online. 60K interrupts/sec on the cpu seems like a very bad amount.

The main symptom is that when I play Battlefield 4 the CPU spikes randomly causing FPS spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably DPCs (deferred procedure calls). Run this program to check.

http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml

If you have a lot of red spikes, then you have a driver problem. The program may give you some hints on the bottom where to look.

Answer (score -1):

- install a stable nvidia driver
- close background programs (the programs which access the disk are your first target)
- select a performance power profile
- see if windows update installed any new drivers recently. uninstall any unusual, "incompatible" or beta drivers. find a safe(stable, likely to work) driver provided by OEM for all suspicious devices.(network, gpu are your first few targets)
- check your antivirus if it's running a scan
- check for conflicting antivirus software(make sure you are not running two at the same time)
- latency mon said highest running cyclpe was tcp-ip related. **check your network adapters drivers. roll back to drivers provided by OEM if you "feel it"**